# Dates over year 2035 getting shifted back by 100 years in the jsp after Ajax call

Tags: jquery, datatables, freemarker

I'm populating a table and displaying it using a freeMarker template and the very first time the list items are loaded up everything is displayed correctly. However, if I then run an Ajax call to save an item, which necessitates in passing the list back and reloading once the ajax call is completed, I find that the records with dates over the year 2035 are counting from 1935 instead.
This is the format I'm using

```
 <td><@s.date name="itemList[${item_index?}].expDate" format="MM/dd/yyyy"/></td>
```

I've also tried other formats to narrow down the issue but I'm getting the same behavior

```
 <td>${item.expDate?string("MM/dd/yyyy")}</td>
```

I'd appreciate if anyone can point me to where this is coming from.

Here is what I found so far since posting the question.
Year change is happening when data is sent back from the web page to save.
I see the same behavior from an earlier version where data flow is 
`Jsp(Data Loaded)-><save>->FreeMarker` instead of the current flow `Jsp(Select Filter)->FreeMarker(Data Loaded)-><save>->FreeMarker` - so it's not from the FreeMarker.  I switched the Ajax call to a Form submit and the issue is still present. I'm currently looking into it to see if it's coming from dataTables

Comment: no ajax shown here. Provide [mcve]. Also how do you know this is a front end problem? Without any code shown not much anyone can do to help

Comment: It's hardly the problem of formatting a `java.util.Date` to `String` (which is what you do above). Certainly `item.expDate` already stores the wrong `java.util.Date`. At some point in the system there's a `String` to `Date` conversion (the opposite direction), but that string only uses two digit years (35), hence the ambiguity and the wrong choice.